# Remove Locale settings from Logintoboggan

Tags: users, i18n-l10n

I have Logintoboggan installed to handle login/registration.

Upon registering a new user it displays an option to set up Locale Settings - I would like to have this removed but cannot figure out how.

I have disabled the site-wide option for users to be able to change locale settings but it still appears at registration/authorisation.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I seem to have fixed the issue by myself (again). For some reason the site-wide locale settings didn't stick so I just disabled and re-enable Logintoboggan and it works fine now